# Why is Bootstrap so stubborn with not allowing different HTML classes for links?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This seems odd but I can't seem to change the default HTML CSS URL link color from a specific page using bootstrap.

I tried this and still Bootstrap insists on being the blue color that it always is...

Any ideas?

Here is what I tried but with no joy...

```
        .class1 A:link {color: red; text-decoration: none!important;}
        .class1 A:visited {color: red; text-decoration: none!important;}
        .class1 A:active {color: red; text-decoration: none!important;}
        .class1 A:hover {color: red; text-decoration: underline!important;}
```

With the link

```
        <th><a href="" class="class1">Category</a></th>
```

Thanks...

Comment: Change the selectors as `a.class1:link` and so on. in CSS selectors, white-space is descendant combinator, therefore `.class1 A:link` will match all links which are descendants of `.class1`, if any.

Comment: It has nothing to do with bootstrap, your CSS is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes thanks very much that fixed it...

```
        a.class1:link {color: red; text-decoration: none!important;}
        a.class1:visited {color: red; text-decoration: none!important;}
        a.class1:active {color: red; text-decoration: none!important;}
        a.class1:hover {color: red; text-decoration: underline!important;}
```